# Using python to extract the names of every folder in Outlook mailbox

Tags: python, outlook

I'm trying to get a list of all folders' names I see in the outlook email box, by using the following code:

```
import win32com.client

def AllFolders(folders):
    my_list = []
    for folder in folders:
        AllFolders(folder.Folders)
        print(folder.name)
        my_list.append(folder.name)
        return my_list

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
user = outlook.Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
z = AllFolders(outlook.Folders[user].Folders)
```

My problem is: if I remove the `return` I can see all the folders returned by the `print`, but if try to return a list of every folder (basically store what I see in the `print` in a list), I get `z` which is only the first element printed.

How can make a list of every folder name?

Comment: The `return` must be _outside_ of the loop, otherwise your function will exit after just one iteration (and so you get just one folder name)

Comment: But this does not return every element I see in print()

Comment: You recursively call the function, so if you have a folder tree you will `print` all the folders and subfolders, and sub-subfolders... however you don't capture the `return` value, so all the data generated by the recursive calls get lost, and `my_list` only contains the first-level folders

Comment: Is there a way to capture all the folders in all levels, into a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to concatenate to your list the one that's being returned by the recursive call.

I also moved the call (and the `print()` line) after the `my_list.append()` line just to have the subfolders added after their parent.

```
import win32com.client

def AllFolders(folders):
    my_list = []
    for folder in folders:
        print(folder.name)
        my_list.append(folder.name)
        my_list += AllFolders(folder.Folders)
    return my_list

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
user = outlook.Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
z = AllFolders(outlook.Folders[user].Folders)
```

Comment: Understood. Thanks a lot @gimix